# Intent kotlin error val intent = Intent( this, login::class.java )

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-intent, kotlin-flow

I have the following code and am getting an error with the Intent. It is because of the this I am fairly certain.

```
btnsignup.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(
        this, signup::class.java
    )
    startActivity(intent)
}
btnlogin.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(
        this, login::class.java
    )
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

I tried

```
btnsignup.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(
        applicationContext, signup::class.java
    )
    startActivity(intent)
}
btnlogin.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(
        applicationContext, login::class.java
    )
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: Post the error stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, this keyword refers to the current object (in this case, the click listener), not the Activity context required for starting an activity. That's why using this inside a click listener causes an error.

Try doing this:

```
btnsignup.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), SignupActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

btnlogin.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), LoginActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

or replace `requireContext()` with `requireActivity()`.

Using `requireContext()` ensures that you get the context of the fragment, and using `requireActivity()` ensures that you get the context of the parent activity when inside a fragment.

Comment: These methods are available for Fragment methods. Steyrix seems to be starting an activity from another activity. In that case "this" can be replaced with something like "this@YouHostingAcitivty". But the solution anyway depends on the error. There is not stacktrace provided here